# two different separate sections on the same site

Tags: menus, multisite, pages, navigation

I want to make a WordPress site that has on the front page 2 buttons. One for section A and one for section B. I want when someone  clicks on one of those to be redirected to that certain website. Section A has its content with its menu( 4 pages) and section B has also another content with 4 pages and another menu and in WordPress admin panel i should have in total 8 pages from both sections.

How can i make 2 different contents with different menus on the same WordPress? I have searched everywhere and i found a way via multiple sites but it think this is a bit too much.

**Question 1**: How can i make a custom front page where i put my buttons and redirect to that part of a site?

**Question 2** how can i make two parts of a site with different content and display the wanted menu?

LE: 
**Question 1 answer** I made a custom page template and set it as front page and for the two sections. I made 2 pages and made the pages of the two sections child pages of the two main pages so i have now sitename.com/oneOfTheTwoParentPages/InnerPage

**Questin 2 answer** i found a plugin called "menu swapper" that does exactly as its name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How can i make a custom front page where i put my buttons and redirect to that part of a site?

The simplest way to make a very custom front page is `front-page.php` template. It isn't commonly shipped with public themes (since it's near impossible to override), but good fit for a private project.

> how can i make two parts of a site with different content and display the wanted menu?

There are different ways to approach this, depending on *differences* needed between the sections. Are they in markup? Styling? Layout? Specific elements of the page?

The low key approach would be probably to produce two *page templates*, one for each section, and assign them to respective pages as needed.

Comment: Thanks for your help  I really appreciate it. For the second question, both sections will look more or less the same in terms of structure, only the content (text, images, etc) will be changed. Also, both of the sections should have a different menu. Section A with page 1 2 3 4 and section B with 5 6 7 8.